# Currency Format for Mongoose Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

At the moment I have the following stage in my aggregation pipeline:

```
{
    name: '$name',
    price: {
    $concat: [
        '＄',
        {
            $toString: {
                $divide: [
                    '$price',
                    100
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

At the moment, this stage is generating the following price string: $10000.

How can I format the price field to return a comma separated string, such as $10,000?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this package usefull that adds a currency type to Mongoose:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-currency

You could also think of storing the parts seperatly and putting them together again in a front end or query (if possible).

As you can see I am not the most experienced user. maybe someone else has a better idea.